# Get Rest Response from Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using camel to route from SOAP web service to Rest Service. My route is like following.

SOAP Service --> Processor A --> Rest --> Processor B .

I'm using Exchange pattern and Rest is hosted in Jboss Server. My problem is how to get Rest Response ( json string ). When i get in message in Processor B it contains the output message or processor A.

```
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:serviceA"/>
        <process ref="processorA" /> 
        <to uri="cxfrs:bean:serviceRest"/>
        <process ref="processorB"/>
    </route>
  </camelContxt>
```

I'm new to camel. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer with the help of friends. It was error in fasterxml jason provider. I changed the json provider to codehaus

```
<cxf:rsClient id="serviceRest" address="http://localhost:8080/rest-test/rest"
              serviceClass="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient" loggingFeatureEnabled="true" >
    <cxf:providers>
        <ref bean="jasonProvider"/>
    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsClient> 

<bean id="jasonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
```

Now i have the json response in exchange.

Comment: Did you have any issues with your JacksonJsonProvider.class not being available across the CXF bus or Blueprint bus? I keep getting an obscure error about a missing url's Observer like like in this   http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/quot-Can-t-find-the-the-request-for-s-Observer-quot-after-update-to-2-4-1-td4622135.html and https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CXF-5551?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to the REST response in the proxessorB by referencing the exchange in message.

Comment: No I'm getting DTO which i passed to processorA from exchange. Log shows following exception. `...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of javax.ws.rs.core.Response, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: {"id":"e240513a-d997-490d-8d4c-9bc8e10391b6","data":{"key1":"value2"}}; line: 1, column: 1]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163) [jackson-databind-2.0.2.jar:]
 `